# Error during publishing project in weblogic server using eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I'm getting the below error during publishing projects in WebLogic server (using Eclipse IDE).

```
 Error with publish task 'Split Source Mapping Generation Task'.
 Error processing split source mapping:
 'C:/Projects/EnrollmentWS/implementation/lib'='/WEB-INF/lib'

 WebLogic split source deployment only supports resource folder mapping to EAR or 
 web content root.
 Please change the deployment mode to exploded archive in Server Editor.
 Note: I tried after change deployement mode to explode archive.now im getting 'module
 exception'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

May be already solved this issue. I think that error message occurred because not all mappings supported in Deployment Assembly.

Please right click to web project:

```
Properties -> Deployment Assembly
```

and delete /WEB-INF/lib row.

[Here is](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1556828) an explanation:

> If you are mapping external folders to web resources in Deployment
>   Assembly, NOT all the mappings are supported, only resource folder
>   mapping to EAR or web content root are supported in split source. (In
>   your case, mapping to '/WEB-INF/classes/' should be supported, which
>   is a bug we will fix in future release)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after trying to wake up a project made on Maven, i removed the line was say `/WEB-INF/web.xml`, on:

`Properties -> Deployment Assembly`

My configuration is on *Spring Tool Suite* with *Oracle Web Logic Server Tools*, downloaded from Marketplace, and after updated using the [Luna OEPE plugin via url](http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.8.1/luna/repository) Deploying a WAR solution to WebLogic 12.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.....

> 1. Stop the server
> 2. Right click on Oracle server and go to Properties.
> 3. Go to WebLogic > Publishing
> 4. Select Publish as an explode archive
> 5. Go to your domain path
>
>    ```
>    C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\Domain_Name\servers\AdminServer
>    ```
> 6. Delete everything "**except security**".
> 7. Now restart the server. It will work fine.

Comment: This solved my issue. I am running a WebLogic 12.2.1 R2 server, and the "Publish as a virtual application" option was checked. Make sure to change it to "Publish as an exploded archive".

Comment: Publishing should work also as a virtual application. This is actually only a work-around that does not explain why the application cannot be published as a virtual one